# how to solve active record $this->db->insert() to achieve an ‘INSERT IGNORE INTO’ statement?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

how to solve active record `$this->db->insert()` to achieve an `INSERT IGNORE INTO` statement?

I have googled it long time, but failed to find solution

Comment: If you can't find better solution you can always use `$this->db->query($yourCustomSqlQuery);`.

Comment: i am inserting record using ajax so there will be chance to insert duplicate record, so i want to use insert ignore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my working script! try this

```
$inserting_data=array('user_id'=>$user_id,
         'user_name'=>$user_name,
         'id'=>$product_id,
         'cost'=>$click_cost,
         'price'=>$current_winner_amount,
         'auction_price'=>$new_value,          
         'date'=>$this->general->get_local_time('time'),
         'type'=>'A');

$insert_query = $this->db->insert_string('mytbl', $inserting_data);
$insert_query = str_replace('INSERT INTO', 'INSERT IGNORE INTO', $insert_query);  
$this->db->query($insert_query);
```

Comment: Thanx @webGautam i will try and inform you :)